# MySQL tables pattern for event calendar

Tags: mysql, performance, calendar

I've been developing a PHP app recently that is aimed at helping Doctors & patients getting in touch and also uses FullCalendar for the doctor So he can manage his events.
My problem is: as I learned coding by myself, I have not learned how to decide whether to use this or that DB organisation.
Currently, the app creates a new table for each new subscription (Doctors only) that is named `event_[$doctor_id]` but I have to admit I'm scared by the perspective of having 3000 users!

My needs are:

- keep a ref for each event during 2 years after its date (but not necessarily in the same dB table)
- events younger than 6 months need to be visible in the calendar
- to avoid errors, events are never (almost) deleted from the db - they are just disabled in order to allow the user to repair a 2 weeks old mistake

I Was considering using date named tables like "201303" for all the events taking place in March 2013, and then use a bot every month that will somehow save the oldest information (6 months + old) in a specific table or even in a file.

But as the changes might take me a few hours, I'd appreciate some advice from you people!